# how to doing group with two cels in a single sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my brief snipt:

```
select * from tbl_test
```

[image]

What I want to do is:

1.

```
select g_size, sum(g_num)
from tbl_test
group by g_size
```

2.

```
select m_size, sum(m_num)
from tbl_test
group by m_size
```

Here is my question, how can I push all these stuffs into **one single** sql string?
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want single row for eigher single g_size or m_size then you can't do in single sql, but if it is okay for you that there can be multiple row for 1st group by field then you can do-

For example if you have one more row g_size=5, g_num=1, m_size=2, m_num=1 and you use below query-

```
select g_size, sum(g_num),m_size, sum(m_num) 
from mytable 
group by g_size,by m_size;
```

then you will get 2 rows for g_size=5 as per below-

g_size= 5, sum(g_num)=5, m_size=1, sum(m_num)=30 
and
g_size= 5, sum(g_num)=1, m_size=2, sum(m_num)=1

Further you can use with rollup function which will first provide sub-total (m_size wise) and then total (g_size wise) and at the end grand total (all m_size grand total).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the columns and the group by:

```
select g_size, sum(g_num),m_size, sum(m_num) from tbl_test group by g_size, m_size;
```